# Are C# primitive data types part of the language?

Tags: c#, .net

In C++ the compiler *knows* about primitive data types such as `int`, but in C# these are basically structures (e.g. `System.Int32`). But can I assume that C# *knows* about these types. I think that it does, because an `int` literal in C# is basically an instance of `System.Int32`. For example this will work:

```
Console.WriteLine((12345).GetType());
```

Output:

```
System.Int32
```

Comment: System.Int32 is a struct and int is just an alias for it. and System.Int32 is a part of .NET,

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int16-int32-int64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# compiler *knows* about primitive data types. Whenever the compiler encounters the addition operator `a + b`, it calls an appropriate static method `operator +`.

However if operands have primitive types, it generates IL code for direct computation.

But usually the compiler and CLR are trying to pretend that primitive types are the same as any other.

In additional, as has been written, the compiler uses aliases for some basic types, such as `int`, `char`, `bool`, and so on.

Comment: So for example when adding `System.Int32 + System.Int32` there is no overloaded function to be called in the `System.Int32` class, but rather the C# compiler will directly generates IL code for this computation?

Comment: Yes, it's, the `System.Int32` type has no methods `op_Add` or `op_Equality` at all. By the way, `System.String` has `op_Equality`, but has no `op_Add`, so `"string" + "string2"` is compiled as call the `Concat` static method.

Comment: So does that means that C# knows about primitive data types, and also knows about `System.String` class (even though with `System.String` it only replaces the `+` with the `Concat` static method)?

Comment: C# compiler knows about `+` for strings, about `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` for integers, about `+=` and `-=` for delegates, and so on. It compiles these operators to IL instructions for adding/subtracting/etc. for integers; to `String.Concat` for strings; to `Delegate.Combine` for delegates. Also it knows about `bool` type and generates IL compare instructions for `if` or `?:` operator. The class `System.String` also can be considered "primitive" since the compiler understand string constants and can translate `+` to `String.Concat`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, type names like *int* and *bool* are **keywords** in the C# language.  A property that it shares with many languages, including C++.  They currently map to types in the .NET Framework that you already know.  Don't make the mistake of assuming that System.Int32 is a *struct*, it certainly isn't the way it is used on a processor.  It is a type that easily fits in a processor register, super-duper important to make programs run fast.  The struct declaration you can see is only representative for a *boxed* int.  Used to create the illusion that all types, even value types, derive from System.Object.

A language hard-bakes a mapping to a physical processor type only at its peril.  Processors change, rapidly.  The canonical example is the C language, the grand-father of C#, 43 years old already and still very relevant in software development.  Started on a 16-bit computer with 64 KB of memory.  Followed by an island of stability, 32-bit designs were around a long time, able to address 4 GB of memory.  Still relevant on 64-bit machines, the norm today, able to address 256 *terabytes*.  Four billion times as much in just 43 years, quite a stunning improvement.  The C language survived this upheaval by making the type names keywords, just like C# and not presuming type sizes.

Yes, the current C# compiler has strong baked-in knowledge of the types used when the program runs on a machine.  When you say `int` in your program then it emits `System.Int32` in the assembly.  So do the jitter and the CLR, they do most of the heavily lifting of mapping a value type to processor registers and memory.  Will it *forever* emit System.Int32?  Not if it wants to still be relevant 43 years from now.  Or sooner, the most restrictive architectural assumption baked into C# right now is the maximum size of an array.  It can't have more than 2 billion elements, indexing it with an *int* runs out of gas beyond that.  When you have 256 terabytes of memory available already today, that's but a little speck of course.

For comparison, 128-bit processors is a future that here today as well.  IBM sells them by the truck-load.  Some pretty interesting architectural things you can do with that much address space, the notion of a *file* becomes irrelevant.  The entire file system is memory-mapped, if you want to write to a file then you simply write to memory.  Files with more than 2 billion bytes are of course not unusual either today.

There are a few technical road-blocks to clear before it is *truly* necessary, hard disks are too slow and memory bus bandwidth too low, garbage collecting a terabyte heap is going to freeze your program for a while :)  We'll have to wait and see.

Comment: When you say "strong baked-in knowledge of the types used when the program runs on a machine", does this mean `System.Int32` is expected to be the `System.Int32` of the CLR? What about things like .NET native or [SharpLang](https://github.com/xen2/SharpLang) that don't bundle the CLR or its types? If they implement `Int32` differently, are they violating the C# language spec?

Comment: you are wrong. C# **Does** specify precisely the size of it's `int ` , `long` and `double` types. infact they are just synonyms for Int32 Int64 and Float64 . C# does this to avoid the ambiguity and bugs that arise in C from not knowing the size on anything. Also C# doesn't intend to survive for 43 years in its current version. in 42 years they'll just release a new version with breaking changes.

Comment: @Asad `System.Int32` is not a part of C#'s spec or any other language. it's a part of the CLR, only the CLR implements it. languages rely on it.

Comment: @AK_ So would it not be correct to say that C# doesn't actually "know" about or specify the primitive types that its keywords alias to? That is, in other words, "C# primitive data types are **not** part of the language"?

Comment: @Asad no. It would be absolutely wrong. read the spec linked in my answer.

Comment: The most wonderful thing you can do with a language spec is change it.  Happened several times to the C language spec as well.  Everybody still calls it C.  A C program written 43 years ago is still pretty likely to run correctly, even though it uses drastically different runtime types.  No reason whatsoever to assume that this won't happen with a C# program as well, other than a lack of imagination what the future will hold.

Comment: sometimes it is sometimes it isn't. C# 1.0 is incompatible with C# 2.0, also C# 5.0 with C# 4.0. C++11 is also incompatible  with c++ 2003. just a few examples... if in the future a C# spec will no longer define `int` to be a synonym for `Int32` this will also be a breaking change.

Comment: @AK_ I'm a bit confused. On the one hand, you are saying: "`System.Int32` is not a part of C#'s spec or any other language". On the other, you are saying it would be absolutely wrong to say "primitive data types are not part of the language". By "being part of the language" I am assuming what is meant is that behavior of the primitive type is specified and described as part of the language specification.

Comment: @AK_ For example, you could say the types in the language support library in C++ are *part of the language*, because they are specified and their behavior described in the actual language standard. A standard compliant C++ compiler cannot exist without implementing `numeric_limits` in a very specific way, for example, so `numeric_limits` is part of the language.

Comment: @Asad there two relevant specifications here. the first is the CLR (Common Language Run time) - the heart of the .Net Framework. A part of this spec is a description of types that all .Net languages must implement (called CTS) these include `System.Int32` , `System.String` etc... The C# spec is based on the CLR spec,  and just defines the `int` keyword to mean `Int32` as defined in the CLR spec.

Answer (score 1):

Any data types, the compiler directly supports are called "Primitive data types".

In C#, you could allocate an integer by using following syntax:

```
System.Int32 a = new System.Int32();
```

But many compilers(including c#) allow us to use the following syntax:

```
int a = 0;
```

We could also use as following:

```
System.Int32 a = 0;
int a = new int();
```

All these maps directly to the System.Int32 type.

i.e. All the primitive data types in C# directly maps to types existing in the frame work class library(FCL).

Also as mentioned in the book "CLR via c#", when you are using,

```
Int a = 0;
```

you can think that the C# compiler automatically assumes that there is an Using directive in the source file like:

```
Using int = System.Int32;
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are.

See the C# specification pages 77-85 :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Also C# is a CLS (Common Language Specification) complaint language, hence it supports everything in the CTS (Common Type System) here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx